# Menu DropDown responsivo, não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Criei um menu `dropdown` responsivo, porém, não está funcionando corretamente.

Na tela mobile, ao clicar no ícone do menu ele é aberto e ao clicar num link do menu ou fora do menu ele fecha.

Porém, fica uma barra aparecendo que só desaparece depois de se clicar no menu novamente.

Segue o código:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
            //Cache dos elementos em variáveis
                var botao = $('.bt_menu');
                var dropDown = $('.dropDown');
                var menu = $('.menu');
                
            botao.on('click', function(event){
                
                dropDown.stop(true,true).slideToggle();
              
                  
                  event.stopPropagation(); 
            });
             
            //Clicando no html vai fechar o dorpDown
            $('html').on('click', function(){
                 dropDown.slideUp();
            });
           });
```

```css
/*Resetando os valores de espaçamento */
 * {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

/*Estilizando a nav da classe menu */
 .menu {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #222;
 font-family: Arial;
 }

/*Estilizando as listas */
 .menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 }

.menu ul li {
 width: 150px;
 float: left;
 }

.menu a {
 padding: 15px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #222;
 color: #fff;
 }

.menu ul ul {
 position: absolute;
 visibility: hidden;
 }

.menu ul li:hover ul {
 visibility: visible;
 }

.menu a:hover {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color: #555;
 }

.menu ul ul li {
 float: none;
 border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
 }

.menu ul ul li a {
 background-color: #069;
 }

/*Criando o label */
 label[for="bt_menu"]{
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #222;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 50px;
 }

#bt_menu {
  display: none; 
 }

label[for="bt_menu"]{
 display: none;
 }

/*Deixando o Menu Responsivo */
@media(max-width: 800px) {
label[for="bt_menu"] {
 display: block;
 }
  
#bt_menu:checked ~ .menu{
 margin-left: 0;
 }
  
.menu{
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: -100%;
 transition: all .4s;
 }
  
.menu ul li {
 width: 100%;
 float: none;
 }
  
.menu ul ul {
 position: static;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 0;
 transition: all 4s;
 }
  
.menu ul li:hover ul {
 height: auto;
 max-height: 200px;
 }
  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" ng-app="myapp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Parsoni</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="bt_menu" class="bt_menu"/>
  <label for="bt_menu">&#9776;</label>

  <nav class="menu">
       <ul id="menu-navegacao" class="dropDown">
            <li><a href="#">Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amigo sem o HTML não da para te ajudar muito

Comment: Provavelmente essa barra preta não é do menu, pq o slideUp resulta em `display: none`. Mas sem o HTML fica impossível fazer qualquer análise precisa.

Comment: Desculpe, mas acho que deixei informações a menos. Fiz o mesmo exemplo no site jsfiddle, segue link:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ept10va/1/

Reparem que ao clicar no menu a primeira vez ele abre e ao clicar em um dos links é recolhido o menu, porém, a barra fica aparecendo. Ela só esconde depois de clicar no menu novamente.

Qualquer ajuda será muito bem vinda.

Obrigado

Comment: Alguem tem alguma sugestão? Estou a alguns dias tentando resolver e não consigo. Obrigado!

Comment: Continuo buscando a solução.. Alguém poderia me auxiliar?Seria de grande ajuda! Mais uma vez agradeço a todos

Comment: A barra que vc fala é a Barra de Scroll vertical que aparece caso a tela não seja muito alta? Mesmo com o menu recolhido fica aparecendo o scroll vertical em telas com pouca altura? É isso http://prntscr.com/medbro?

Comment: Não é a barra de scroll. É a própria ul com os itens do menu. Veja o exemplo aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/2ept10va/1/ o menu só fecha por completo quando é clicado no proprio menu, caso o clique aconteça em um link do menu ele fecha parcialmente e só fecha por completo ao clicar no botão de menu

Answer (score 1):

A solução foi simples, apenas alterei o codigo em javascript para esse:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var botao = document.getElementById('bt_menu');
  $('html').on('click', function(e) {
      if ($(e.target).closest("#clique").length)
          return;

      if (botao.checked === true) {
          botao.checked = false;
      }
  });
  $('.dropDown').on('click', function() {
      if (botao.checked === true) {
          botao.checked = false;
      }
  });
 });
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/206001)

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento João, esse é meu primeiro post no site..